# In R, can I make the table() function return the number of NA values in a named element?

Tags: r, na

I am using R to summarize a large amount of data for a report. I want to be able to use `lapply()` to generate a list of tables from the `table()` function, from which I can extract my desired statistics. There are a lot of these, so I've written a function to do it. My issue is that I am having difficulty returning the number of missing (`NA`) values even though I have that in each table, because I can't figure out how to tell R that I want the element from `table()` that holds the number of `NA` values. As far as I can tell, R is "naming" that element `NA`...and I can't call that.

I'm trying to avoid writing some complex statement where I say something like `which(is.na(names(element[1]))) | names(element[1])=="var_I_want"` because I feel like that's just really wordy. I was hoping there was some way to either tell R to label the `NA` variable in each table with a character name, or to tell it to pick the one labeled `NA`, but I haven't had much luck yet.

Minimal example:

```
example <- data.frame(ID=c(10,20,30,40,50),
                      V1=c("A","B","A",NA,"C"),
                      V2=c("Dog","Cat",NA,"Cat","Bunny"),
                      V3=c("Yes","No","No","Yes","No"),
                      V4=c("No",NA,"No","No","Yes"),
                      V5=c("No","Yes","Yes",NA,"No"))

varlist <- c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V5")

list_o_tables <- lapply(X=example[varlist],FUN=table,useNA="always")

list(V1=list_o_tables[["V1"]]["A"],
     V2=list_o_tables[["V2"]]["Cat"],
     V3=list_o_tables[["V3"]]["Yes"],
     V4=list_o_tables[["V4"]]["Yes"],
     V5=list_o_tables[["V5"]]["Yes"])
```

What I get:

```
$V1
A 
2 

$V2
Cat 
  2 

$V3
Yes 
  2 

$V4
Yes 
  1 

$V5
Yes 
  2
```

What I'd like:

```
$V1
A     <NA>
2       1

$V2
Cat   <NA>
  2     1

$V3
Yes   <NA> 
  2     0

$V4
Yes   <NA> 
  1     1

$V5
Yes   <NA> 
  2     1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ugly (IMHO) but it works:

```
my_table <- function(x){
    setNames(table(x,useNA = "always"),c(sort(unique(x[!is.na(x)])),'NA'))
}
```

So you'd `lapply` this instead, and then you'd have access to the `NA` column.

Looking more closely, this is rooted in the behavior of `factor`:

```
levels(factor(c(1,NA,2),exclude = NULL))
[1] "1" "2" NA
```

My recollection is that the distinction between a factor level of `NA` versus `"NA"` has been at the very least a source of confusion in R in the past. I feel like I've seen some debates about the merits of this on r-devel, but I can't recall for sure at the moment.

So the issue is, if you have a factor with `NA` values, what do you call the levels? Technically, this is correct, one of the levels is "missing" not literally "NA". It would be nice (IMHO) if `table` didn't adhere to this quite so strictly, though.

Comment: I figured something like this would work, but I also thought I was missing some obvious R feature that would do this. I agree it's not pretty, but it does get the job done.

Comment: @TARehman It really seems like the name of the `NA` category should be set to the character `<NA>` rather than _literally_ being `NA`. I can't even really think of a reason why the way it is would be useful...

Comment: Agreed. I went at it for about an hour before coming to SO to ask because I was like "This can't possibly be the intended functionality..." :P

Comment: Looking at the way `table` treats `NA` something like `lapply( list_o_tables , tail , 1 )` could be useful....

Answer (score 5):

Why not just fix the names up after the fact?

```
tables <- lapply(example[-1], table, useNA = "ifany")

fix_names <- function(x) {
  names(x)[is.na(names(x))] <- "<NA>"
  x
}
lapply(tables, fix_names)
```

Answer (score 3):

`tab[match(NA, names(tab))]` seems to work where `tab[NA]`,  `tab[NA_character_]`, `tab["NA_character_"]`, `tab["<NA>"]`, etc. etc. fail...

```
f <- function(nms, obj) {
    obj[sapply(c(nms, NA), function(X) match(X, names(obj)))]
}

f("Cat", list_o_tables[["V2"]])
#  Cat <NA> 
#    2    1 

mapply(f, list("A", "Cat", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), list_o_tables, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
# [[1]]
# 
#    A <NA> 
#    2    1 
# 
# [[2]]
# 
#  Cat <NA> 
#    2    1 
# 
# [[3]]
# 
#  Yes <NA> 
#    2    0 
# 
# [[4]]
# 
#  Yes <NA> 
#    1    1 
# 
# [[5]]
# 
#  Yes <NA> 
#    2    1
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought at first, too! ;)

Comment: Right - note how your <NA> columns contain NA. It's quite annoying. :D

Comment: Thanks @joran & TARehman. Edited to fix. This sure is a weird corner case, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

When you set `useNA="always"`, `table()` *always* adds `NA` as the last result, therefore one way to do this would be to use `tail` to your advantage. Assuming we have your `list` from above (which I'll call `l1`)...

```
l1 <- list(V1=list_o_tables[["V1"]]["A"],
     V2=list_o_tables[["V2"]]["Cat"],
     V3=list_o_tables[["V3"]]["Yes"],
     V4=list_o_tables[["V4"]]["Yes"],
     V5=list_o_tables[["V5"]]["Yes"])
```

We can get the `NA` and then join them like this..

```
l2 <- lapply( list_o_tables , tail , 1 )
mapply( c , l1, l2 , SIMPLIFY = FALSE )
#$V1
#   A <NA> 
#   2    1 

#$V2
# Cat <NA> 
#   2    1 

#$V3
# Yes <NA> 
#   2    0 

#$V4
# Yes <NA> 
#   1    1 

#$V5
# Yes <NA> 
#   2    1
```