# How to read the NA count in a table?

Tags: r

If I use `useNA="always"`for a table(), the resulting object will contain an entry with the name `NA` (not `"NA"`). Is there any way to read this value?

I found a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20444934/336311) (last row), but I guess there is a much more elegant solution?!

```
test = table(c(1,1,2,2,3,3,NA), useNA="always")
print(test[NA])      # <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
print(test[[NA]])    # subscript out of bounds
print(test["<NA>"])  # NA

test[which(is.na(names(test)))[1]]  # Works: 1, but not exactly ... elegant
```

Thanks

Comment: Is `test[is.na(names(test))]` sufficiently elegant?

Comment: I hoped there was a way to directly address the `NA` - without a workaround by the numeric index.
Actually, this is more a question of elegance than of practice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the count of `NA` values is the last one, you can use `tail(test, 1)`.

As I understood you are looking for the extract using character indices when some name is `NA`. I believe it is not possible to extract directly the object with `NA` name. From [the Extract documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/Extract):

> Neither empty ("") nor NA indices match any names, not even empty nor
>   missing names. If any object has no names or appropriate dimnames,
>   they are taken as all "" and so match nothing.

Comment: At least, that's less code :) I was wondering if there is a solution that can directly address the `NA`entry -- without using the `NA`'s column position in the table/data.frame/list/etc...

Comment: Your question is about object `table`. What do you mean by data.frame/list/etc in the comment?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion ... the `table`-case is just the most obvious one. If doing `as.list(table(...))` you create a list with one `NA` index. I noticed, you cannot create such a list via `list(NA=1, ...)`. Starting here, I was interested in a way to address an `NA` index directly.